# Store object from popup in background page in a webextension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have **web-extension** working in Chrome where a simple object, {"a":1,"b":2}, is created in the extensions popup and stored in a variable of the background page.

Popup(extention page-action/browser-action) page

```
var f = {
    from: form.from.value,
    to: form.to.value,
};
var b = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
b.save(f);
```

In background page:

```
var saved = {};

function save(f) {
    saved["f"] = f;
}
```

Later, after the page-action popup is closed the variable `saved` is accessed on another page.

```
var b = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
console.log(b.saved)
```

*Note that "saved" does not imply the value is safe, it's only an in memory temporary storage*

**1. Desired behaviour**
In chrome this works as expected, the value of `saved` is logged.

**2. Specific error**
When I run the same web-extension in Firefox I get this message in the console

> can't access dead object

The [Mozilla page](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/) suggest contacting the extension author(me) but doesn't say how, only "don't".

How can I "disconnect" the object from the popup page?

Is there perhaps a recommended approach that works on all browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I have updated the question and hope you can come with some insights in why as opposed to the quick workaround I've added myself.    

More specifically is this a trend in more strict behavior we should plan for in all browsers.

Comment: I've encountered this in Firefox before while doing something similar. My expectation is the Object is created in the popup scope, which is destroyed (w/o regard to a ref. to that Object existing outside the scope). It's debatable as to which of hard destroy/keep alive (of the scope) is desirable. Hard destroy closes a possible memory leaks/potential security issues. The Object ref. keeping the scope alive would cause memory to leak throughout Firefox (see how often accessing a dead Object is attempted in the Browser Console). I'll try to look for how I handled it later today.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by serializing and deserializing the objects in the background scripts.

So instead of

```
var b = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
b.keep["key"] == value;
```

I had to do

```
var b = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
b.saveKeep("key", value);
```

and in the background page scripts

```
function saveKeep(key, value){
    keep[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
}
```